# CmisSync not building correctly

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, cmis

Trying to install [CmisSync](http://cmissync.com) through Visual Studio 2013 and I keep getting an exception to do with the AppData Roaming folder.

```
File Path; AppData/Roaming/cmissync/config.xml
```

When I looked in the file, it was blank.

What I've done so far is download the zipped source file. Extracted it, opened the windows sln file and built the project. When I go to debug I get an exception. Also DotCMIS project is unavailable.
Below is the exception.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
HResult=-2146233079
Message=There is an error in XML document (0, 0).
Source=System.Xml
StackTrace:
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(TextReader textReader)
at CmisSync.Lib.Config.Load() in e:\Users\davette\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CmisSync-master\CmisSync.Lib\Config.cs:line 345
at CmisSync.Lib.Config..ctor(String fullPath) in e:\Users\davette\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CmisSync-master\CmisSync.Lib\Config.cs:line 164
at CmisSync.Lib.ConfigManager.get_CurrentConfig() in e:\Users\davette\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CmisSync-master\CmisSync.Lib\ConfigManager.cs:line 40
at CmisSync.Lib.Sync.ConfigMigration.CheckForDuplicatedLog4NetElement() in e:\Users\davette\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CmisSync-master\CmisSync.Lib\ConfigMigration.cs:line 38
at CmisSync.Lib.Sync.ConfigMigration.Migrate() in e:\Users\davette\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CmisSync-master\CmisSync.Lib\ConfigMigration.cs:line 27
at CmisSync.Program.Main(String[] args) in e:\Users\davette\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CmisSync-master\CmisSync\Program.cs:line 74
at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
InnerException: System.Xml.XmlException
HResult=-2146232000
Message=Root element is missing.
Source=System.Xml
LineNumber=0
LinePosition=0
SourceUri=""
StackTrace:
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
at System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent()
at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderSyncConfig.Read9_CmisSync()
InnerException:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had this problem please look [here](https://github.com/aegif/CmisSync/issues/323).

The long and short of it is delete the config file, and re-run the debug.

Everything should then work.

Comment: Exactly! I am the creator of CmisSync, CmisSync had a bug where it would blank the XML files in some unlucky circumstances. We fixed this bug a month ago, so it should not happen anymore. Anyone having the same problem, please update CmisSync and follow PurpleSmurph's instructions: stop, delete the empty XML file, start.